# How to keep the functionality of Enabled = False, whilst keeping the styles of Enabled = True?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` that looks like this:

[image]

Here's my current code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
          ColumnWidth="100" ColumnHeaderHeight="50" RowHeight="50" RowHeaderWidth="115" Padding="5"
          BorderBrush="#FF646464" FontSize="18" FontFamily="Segoe UI"
          CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False"
          Focusable="False" IsEnabled="False" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.Background>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFFFFFC8"/>
    </DataGrid.Background>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}" Binding="{Binding In}" Header="In"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}" Binding="{Binding Out}" Header="Out"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}" Binding="{Binding Hours}" Header="Hours"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFFC8"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkSlateGray"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1, 2"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <DataGrid.RowBackground>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent"/>
    </DataGrid.RowBackground>
    <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRowHeader}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFFFFFC8"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkSlateGray"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2, 1"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
    <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=Item.Day}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
</DataGrid>
```

I'd like to keep the `DataGrid` disabled, functionality-wise, but I'd like to keep the text black (rather than grey). How can I achieve this?

My `DataGridCellStyle` is within the `<Window.Resources>`:

```
<Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: please post your `DataGridCellStyle`

Comment: Isn't IsReadOnly what your are looking for perhaps? - NVM I see you already use that.

Comment: If you're just trying to prevent editing - then only set IsReadOnly, and leave IsEnabled true.

Comment: @Mike This has the effect that when you click a row, the text for that row goes white. Also, the Select All button in the top-left remains enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to mess with Styles, just set the DataGrid's `IsHitTestVisible` to `False`.

You can then also remove `CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" Focusable="False"`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DataGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
          ColumnWidth="100" ColumnHeaderHeight="50" RowHeight="50" RowHeaderWidth="115" Padding="5"
          BorderBrush="#FF646464" FontSize="18" FontFamily="Segoe UI"
          IsHitTestVisible="False">
....
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to override the default disabled brushes in your datagrid by putting the color with the same key that the controls use on IsEnable=False in the resources.

```
  <DataGrid.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush 
       x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}" 
       Color="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextColor}" />
  </DataGrid.Resources>
```

P.S. I did not check the default cell template of the datagrid, I just assumed it uses GrayTextBrushKey, so check that first.